# How to grab specific variables from a row for CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

[Imported file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzN03.png)

```
import csv

fields = [
    "RowNum",
    "PlayerNum",
    "Name",
    "Position",
    "Age",
    "ThrowHand",
    "BatHand",
    "Height",
    "Weight",
    "Birthdate",
    "RookieYear"
]

with open("astroRoster.txt") as astroFiles:
    astroRoster = csv.DictReader(astroFiles, fields)
    print("\t Player names and jersey numbers:")
    for element in astroRoster:
        print(f'{element["Name"]}: {element["PlayerNum"]}')

with open("astroRoster.txt") as astroFiles:
    astroRoster = csv.DictReader(astroFiles, fields)
    print("\t Tallest player and height:")
    for element in astroRoster:
        print(f'{element["Name"][17]}: {element["Height"][17]}') #this is where i have no idea what i'm doing
```

I am trying to print out the tallest player and their height from my .txt file, a photo is attached of the file. But I am unsure how to grab specific elements. I want to be able to print out the average of their weights and age and other specific things but I don't know / understand how. I am a super beginner so I am sorry if this is a dumb question, I just can't figure it out :(

Comment: i posted a link to the file

Comment: No you haven't, that's not a link to the file, it's a link to an **image** of what's in the file — which isn't that helpful. Suggest you add some or all of what's in the file to your question as _text_.

Answer (score 0):

For tabular data pandas is a fantastic tool!
Print the data you can use something like below(untested). You will need to modify it to save to a text file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yourcsv",names=["RowNum","PlayerNum","Name","Position","Age","ThrowHand","BatHand","Height","Weight","Birthdate","RookieYear"])
for row in df.rows:
   print row['Name'], row['PlayerNum'], row['Height']
```

Comment: i unfortunately can't use any modules :(